# Sonar-qube 4.5.1 custom rules plugin is not working

Tags: maven-2, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I have created a custom rule plugin using [custom rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src) code snippet. Now I have added another rule which will show error when a anonymous class has more than 30 lines.
I have build the custom rule plugin jar using `mvn package` command and put in in sonar server extension/plugin and restarted the server.
my corresponding rule can be viewed from sonar server but rule cannot analyze the the code though there is a class with anonymous class with loc >30 lines. my custom rule is given below.

```
@Rule(
  key = AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck.KEY,
    name = "Avoid  too big classes",
    description = "avoid too bid classes",
  tags = {"brain-overload"},
  priority = Priority.MAJOR)
@BelongsToProfile(title = "Sonar way", priority = Priority.MAJOR)
public class AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck extends BaseTreeVisitor implements JavaFileScanner {
public static final String KEY = "AD0001";
  private static final RuleKey RULE_KEY = RuleKey.of(MyJavaRulesDefinition.REPOSITORY_KEY, KEY);
  private static final int DEFAULT_MAX = 30;

  @RuleProperty(defaultValue = "" + DEFAULT_MAX)
  public int max = DEFAULT_MAX;

  private JavaFileScannerContext context;
  /**
   * Flag to skip check for class bodies of EnumConstants.
   */
  private boolean isEnumConstantBody;

  @Override
  public void scanFile(JavaFileScannerContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    isEnumConstantBody = false;
    scan(context.getTree());
  }

  @Override
  public void visitNewClass(NewClassTree tree) {
    if (tree.classBody() != null && !isEnumConstantBody) {
      int lines = getNumberOfLines(tree.classBody());
      if (lines > max) {
        context.addIssue(tree, RULE_KEY, "Reduce this anonymous class number of lines from " + lines + " to at most " + max + ", or make it a named class.");
      }
    }
    isEnumConstantBody = false;
    super.visitNewClass(tree);
  }

  @Override
  public void visitEnumConstant(EnumConstantTree tree) {
    isEnumConstantBody = true;
    super.visitEnumConstant(tree);
  }

  @Override
  public void visitLambdaExpression(LambdaExpressionTree lambdaExpressionTree) {
    int lines = getNumberOfLines(((JavaTree) lambdaExpressionTree.body()).getAstNode());
    if (lines > max) {
      context.addIssue(lambdaExpressionTree, RULE_KEY, "Reduce this lambda expression number of lines from " + lines + " to at most " + max + ".");
    }
    super.visitLambdaExpression(lambdaExpressionTree);
  }

  private int getNumberOfLines(ClassTree classTree) {
    int startLine = ((InternalSyntaxToken) classTree.openBraceToken()).getLine();
    int endline = ((InternalSyntaxToken) classTree.closeBraceToken()).getLine();
    return endline - startLine + 1;
  }

  private int getNumberOfLines(AstNode node) {
    return node.getLastToken().getLine() - node.getTokenLine() + 1;
  }

}
```

Now do I need to do any thing more to get the rule hit?

One more thing 
after putting the plugin jar in plugin folder if i run the analyzer using `mvn sonar:sonar` a error occures

```
Embedded error: org/sonar/java/model/InternalSyntaxToken
org.sonar.java.model.InternalSyntaxToken
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:103)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org/sonar/java/model/InternalSyntaxToken
        at org.sonar.maven.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:37)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:98)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/java/model/InternalSyntaxToken
        at org.sonar.samples.java.AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck.getNumberOfLines(AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck.java:78)
        at org.sonar.samples.java.AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck.visitNewClass(AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck.java:53)
        at org.sonar.java.model.expression.NewClassTreeImpl.accept(NewClassTreeImpl.java:126)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitVariable(BaseTreeVisitor.java:291)
        at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.VariableTreeImpl.accept(VariableTreeImpl.java:180)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:36)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitClass(BaseTreeVisitor.java:69)
        at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:201)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:36)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitClass(BaseTreeVisitor.java:69)
        at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:201)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:36)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(BaseTreeVisitor.java:55)
        at org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree$CompilationUnitTreeImpl.accept(JavaTree.java:202)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42)
        at org.sonar.samples.java.AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck.scanFile(AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck.java:47)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
        at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.walkAndVisit(AstWalker.java:67)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:107)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.scan(AstScanner.java:75)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:122)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:115)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:173)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.java.model.InternalSyntaxToken
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
        ... 82 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you encounter this error is that the code of the [AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/AnonymousClassesTooBigCheck.java) is using internal APIs, here `InternalSyntaxToken` is not supposed to be used directly and thus fails at runtime (you might notice that none of the example in the [custom rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src) code snippet is using this class).